# How to read a nested Json with unique values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a source json of steam reviews, in the format:

```
{
  "reviews": {
    "69245216": {
      "recommendationid": "69245216",
      "author": {
        "steamid": "76561198166378463",
        "num_games_owned": 31,
        "num_reviews": 4,
        "playtime_forever": 60198,
        "playtime_last_two_weeks": 5899,
        "last_played": 1589654367
      },
      "language": "english",
      "review": "Me:*Playing Heroes of Hammrwatch\nAlso me 1 year later:*Playing Heroes of Hammrwatch\nIt's one of the best rougelites I've ever played. You can easly say that by the amount of hours I have on this game. I also have every achievement in the game.\nThe things I don't like about this game:\n-Limit- The game has limits like max damage you can deal. This is not that big problem because you would have to play this game as long as me to hit \"the wall\". And its because the damage is codded in 32bit number which makes the limit around 2 billion.\n-Tax- There is tax in the game for gold which scales with the amount of gold you have on you what makes no sense.\nThe things I like about this game:\n-Music- There are different themed ones depending on the act you are on.\n-Pixel Art-\n-Graphics- Game feels so smooth.\n-Classes- 9 Playable characters with unique sets.\n-Challanging gameplay- You can get far on the first run if you play good.\n-Bosses- There is a boss for every act in the game with different skills which can be harder for some characters.\n-Replayable- There are higher difficulty levels called NewGamePlus (NG+).\n-COOP- Playing with friends makes the game much better and also the game balances the difficulty.\n-DLC- There are DLCs for the game with new content (locations,game modes and playable characters).\n-Builds- There are different combination of items which makes game interesting in some situations.\n-Quality of life- Game has many quality of life improvements\n-Price- The game is very cheap. The only price is your soul beacuse you won't stop playing it! ;)\n\n\n\n",
      "timestamp_created": 1589644982,
      "timestamp_updated": 1589644982,
      "voted_up": true,
      "votes_up": 0,
      "votes_funny": 0,
      "weighted_vote_score": 0,
      "comment_count": 0,
      "steam_purchase": true,
      "received_for_free": false,
      "written_during_early_access": false
    },
    "69236471": {
      "recommendationid": "69236471",
      "author": {
        "steamid": "76561198279405449",
        "num_games_owned": 595,
        "num_reviews": 46,
        "playtime_forever": 1559,
        "playtime_last_two_weeks": 1559,
        "last_played": 1589652037
      },
      "language": "english",
      "review": "Yes",
      "timestamp_created": 1589635540,
      "timestamp_updated": 1589635540,
      "voted_up": true,
      "votes_up": 0,
      "votes_funny": 0,
      "weighted_vote_score": 0,
      "comment_count": 0,
      "steam_purchase": true,
      "received_for_free": false,
      "written_during_early_access": false
    },
    "69226790": {
      "recommendationid": "69226790",
      "author": {
        "steamid": "76561198004456693",
        "num_games_owned": 82,
        "num_reviews": 14,
        "playtime_forever": 216,
        "playtime_last_two_weeks": 216,
        "last_played": 1589579174
      },
      "language": "english",
      "review": "I really like how Hipshot/Crackshell is improving their formula from game to game. Altough SS Bogus Detour I didn't really like, I see how they implemented what they've learnt there to this game. Visuals just keep getting better and better and for that I really can't wait to see Hammerwatch 2 (check their YoutTube channel, early footage is out there).\nGameplay-wise I think it's a perfect match between the classic Hammerwatch feeling and a rougelike setting. My only issue with this game is the random map generator. Most of the time like 1/5 of all levels are just empty dead-ends. Otherwise highly recommend, already see huge amount of gameplay ahead of me.",
      "timestamp_created": 1589623437,
      "timestamp_updated": 1589623437,
      "voted_up": true,
      "votes_up": 0,
      "votes_funny": 0,
      "weighted_vote_score": 0,
      "comment_count": 0,
      "steam_purchase": true,
      "received_for_free": false,
      "written_during_early_access": false
    },
```

and so on..

reading this in with `df = pd.read_json(r'review_677120.json')`

gives the following

```
                                                    reviews query_summary cursors
69245216  {'recommendationid': '69245216', 'author': {'s...           NaN     NaN
69236471  {'recommendationid': '69236471', 'author': {'s...           NaN     NaN
69226790  {'recommendationid': '69226790', 'author': {'s...           NaN     NaN
```

However I'd like something more along the lines of

```
        steamid             num_games_owned num_reviews playtime_forever playtime_last_two_weeks last_played language review
69245216  76561198166378463 31                       4            60198                     5899   589654367  english  "me..
```

so each line expanded to one row.

I've tried playing around with json_normalize, but none of my attempts seem to work, I either get errors `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'` for `df = json_normalize(df)`

Other attempts have resulted in everything being in one row, and not usable.

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Do you just want these elements: `steamid             num_games_owned num_reviews playtime_forever playtime_last_two_weeks last_played language review`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('content.json') as f:
    # reading in json file
    d = json.load(f)

for id in d['reviews']:
    # pulls nested author information into main dictionary
    for key, val in d['reviews'][id]['author'].items():
        d['reviews'][id][key] = val
    del d['reviews'][id]['author']

print(d)
# OUTPUT:
{
  'reviews': {
  '69245216': {'recommendationid': '69245216', 'language': 'english', 'review': 'Me:*Playing Heroes of Hammrwatch\nAlso me 1 year later:*Playing Heroes of Hammrwatch\nIt\'s one of the best rougelites I\'ve ever played. You can easly say that by the amount of hours I have on this game. I also have every achievement in the game.\nThe things I don\'t like about this game:\n-Limit- The game has limits like max damage you can deal. This is not that big problem because you would have to play this game as long as me to hit "the wall". And its because the damage is codded in 32bit number which makes the limit around 2 billion.\n-Tax- There is tax in the game for gold which scales with the amount of gold you have on you what makes no sense.\nThe things I like about this game:\n-Music- There are different themed ones depending on the act you are on.\n-Pixel Art-\n-Graphics- Game feels so smooth.\n-Classes- 9 Playable characters with unique sets.\n-Challanging gameplay- You can get far on the first run if you play good.\n-Bosses- There is a boss for every act in the game with different skills which can be harder for some characters.\n-Replayable- There are higher difficulty levels called NewGamePlus (NG+).\n-COOP- Playing with friends makes the game much better and also the game balances the difficulty.\n-DLC- There are DLCs for the game with new content (locations,game modes and playable characters).\n-Builds- There are different combination of items which makes game interesting in some situations.\n-Quality of life- Game has many quality of life improvements\n-Price- The game is very cheap. The only price is your soul beacuse you won\'t stop playing it! ;)\n\n\n\n', 'timestamp_created': 1589644982, 'timestamp_updated': 1589644982, 'voted_up': True, 'votes_up': 0, 'votes_funny': 0, 'weighted_vote_score': 0, 'comment_count': 0, 'steam_purchase': True, 'received_for_free': False, 'written_during_early_access': False, 'steamid': '76561198166378463', 'num_games_owned': 31, 'num_reviews': 4, 'playtime_forever': 60198, 'playtime_last_two_weeks': 5899, 'last_played': 1589654367}, 
  '69236471': {'recommendationid': '69236471', 'language': 'english', 'review': 'Yes', 'timestamp_created': 1589635540, 'timestamp_updated': 1589635540, 'voted_up': True, 'votes_up': 0, 'votes_funny': 0, 'weighted_vote_score': 0, 'comment_count': 0, 'steam_purchase': True, 'received_for_free': False, 'written_during_early_access': False, 'steamid': '76561198279405449', 'num_games_owned': 595, 'num_reviews': 46, 'playtime_forever': 1559, 'playtime_last_two_weeks': 1559, 'last_played': 1589652037}, 
  '69226790': {'recommendationid': '69226790', 'language': 'english', 'review': "I really like how Hipshot/Crackshell is improving their formula from game to game. Altough SS Bogus Detour I didn't really like, I see how they implemented what they've learnt there to this game. Visuals just keep getting better and better and for that I really can't wait to see Hammerwatch 2 (check their YoutTube channel, early footage is out there).\nGameplay-wise I think it's a perfect match between the classic Hammerwatch feeling and a rougelike setting. My only issue with this game is the random map generator. Most of the time like 1/5 of all levels are just empty dead-ends. Otherwise highly recommend, already see huge amount of gameplay ahead of me.", 'timestamp_created': 1589623437, 'timestamp_updated': 1589623437, 'voted_up': True, 'votes_up': 0, 'votes_funny': 0, 'weighted_vote_score': 0, 'comment_count': 0, 'steam_purchase': True, 'received_for_free': False, 'written_during_early_access': False, 'steamid': '76561198004456693', 'num_games_owned': 82, 'num_reviews': 14, 'playtime_forever': 216, 'playtime_last_two_weeks': 216, 'last_played': 1589579174}
  }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['reviews'], orient='index')
print(df)
# OUTPUT:
         recommendationid language  ... playtime_last_two_weeks  last_played
69245216         69245216  english  ...                    5899   1589654367
69236471         69236471  english  ...                    1559   1589652037
69226790         69226790  english  ...                     216   1589579174

[3 rows x 19 columns]

print(df.axes)
# OUPUT: 
[Index(['69245216', '69236471', '69226790'], dtype='object'), Index(['recommendationid', 'language', 'review', 'timestamp_created',
       'timestamp_updated', 'voted_up', 'votes_up', 'votes_funny',
       'weighted_vote_score', 'comment_count', 'steam_purchase',
       'received_for_free', 'written_during_early_access', 'steamid',
       'num_games_owned', 'num_reviews', 'playtime_forever',
       'playtime_last_two_weeks', 'last_played'],
      dtype='object')]
```